# My desktop is gone

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I recently was infected with the " System repair" program. I deleted all the Files and registry items that I was instructed to delete and the infection seems to be gone but I don't have a desktop. I am able to go to the start Icon and run all the programs. Am I able to get my desktop back??

Comment: Right click blank space (ie your wallpaper) -> View -> Show Desktop Icons ?

Comment: @todda: No, that's not what it is.

Comment: @Bill, what happens when you right-click the desktop? Do you see a menu? What items are greyed? Can you open shortcuts? Can you open an Explorer window? If so, what do you see in it?

Answer (score 1):

You can try [unhide.exe.](http://download.bleepingcomputer.com/grinler/unhide.exe)  It's explained on [this virus removal page](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/virus-removal/remove-windows-repair), near the bottom.  If you haven't performed all of the other steps on that page, you might want to do those as well.